# How many tours exist in a connected graph with V vertices?

Tags: graph, complexity-theory, graph-theory

Assuming every vertex has an edge to every other vertex, how many tours exist in this graph, where you must start a vertex v and end up back at v?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want your tours to be simple - otherwise the answer would be "infinitely many".

Now, your tours can be of three kinds:

- First, the tour that only contains v
- Second, any cycle of length 2 that contains v, i.e., from v, walk to any vertex w and back.  There's n-1 of those.
- Third, any cycle containing v of length 3 or more. All of those have the form "v -> a -> … -> b -> v", where a -> … -> b can be any simple path from a to b that does not contain v. How many simple paths of length k, starting at a, are there? Well, for the first vertex, you can walk from a to any of (n-2) other vertices. For the second vertex, you can choose from (n-3) vertices, and so on. Thus, there are (n-2) * (n-3) * … (n - k - 1) simple paths of length k that start at a and don't include v. Since k can be anything between 1 and n-2, you have  [image: number of paths per vertex a] paths per vertex a - and there are n-1 choices for a.

Summing it all up, you end up with:

[image: Total number of paths]