# An algorithm for finding all the closed trails passing through all the nodes in a multigraph

Tags: algorithm, graph

In a directed, weighted *multigraph*:

1- Which algorithm can find all the directed closed trails , passing through *all the nodes* *at least once*? I attached an example.

[image: Example]

- A trail is a walk in which *all edges are distinct*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_and_path
- A trail must include all the nodes and the nodes should be visited at least once.
- The closed trail starts from a node, let's say x, and it revisits node x at the end.

I am not sure if it is possible to use any algorithms that find Hamiltonian cycles. As far as I know, a Hamiltonian cycle must pass through all the nodes exactly once (except the first and the last node, which is similar), but in my case, the cycles must pass through all the nodes at least once. Hence, I am wondering if I should modify the typical algorithms extracting Hamiltonian cycles to do so.

Furthermore, I am uncertain whether the typical algorithms that find Hamiltonian cycles are effective for the type of multigraphs we are dealing with.

Comment: Hi. Could you please highlight the differences between this question and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76165252/an-algorithm-for-finding-all-the-cycles-and-an-algorithm-for-finding-the-shortes ? It's not obvious at first glance.

Comment: @Stef: I asked two questions in the link you mentioned, and one of them is already answered. As user3386109 suggested, to make the unanswered question (my first question in the mentioned link) clearer, I created it again on a new page. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Any algorithm that can solve this can also solve the Hamilton cycle problem in a regular graph, which is NP complete.  So I wouldn't expect there to be a good algorithm here.

Comment: @btilly: How should I deal with the graphs with two nodes, such as Example 2? As far as I know, a Hamilton cycle includes at least three nodes.
How should I deal with the parallel edges between two nodes?

Comment: I think the first step is to remove the redundant edges, e.g. remove the edge with weight 5. Then find all the cycles in the reduced graph. If there are N cycles in the reduced graph, then there are `N * 2^R` cycles in the original graph, where R is the number of redundant edges. That assumes that two edges (an edge plus a redundant edge) between each pair of nodes that has redundancy.

Comment: @user3386109: As the question says, the cycles must pass through all the nodes (see the Example). I am wondering why you are saying we should find all the cycles.

Comment: Let's define a "tour" as a cycle that passes through all the nodes. Then change the word "cycles" to "tours" in my previous comment.

Comment: @user3386109: Which algorithm can find the tours (a tour passes through all the nodes at least once)? I think the algorithms that find the Hamiltonian cycle cannot be applied in our case, as a node can be visited at least once.

Comment: Have you googled "Travelling Salesman problem"?  What you are looking for is NOT a cycle, which is normally defined as a path that visits no vertex more than once and returns to its starting point.

Comment: @ravenspoint: As far as I am concerned, my question is not related to TSP as it has nothing to do with the shortest cycle. May I ask you what made you to this point respectfuly?

Comment: If there is a cycle then there is an infinite number of cycles, for example 2-4-4-3, 2-4-4-3-2-4-4-3, 2-4-4-3-2-4-4-3-2-4-4-3, ...

Comment: @n.m.: The restriction is that the algorithm starts from a node, let's say x, and passes through all the nodes, and as soon as it revisits node x, the algorithm must stop.

Comment: OK then 2-4-4-3, 2-4-4-4-4-3, 2-4-4-4-4-4-4-3, ... Define properties of the path, not properties of the algorithm.

Comment: @n.m.: I am wondering how I should define the path/cycle! Could you help me with this?

Comment: It would help you a lot if you stopped misusing the term 'cycle'.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_and_path I don't know what you are after. You may want a *circuit* (a closed trail), or you may want a closed walk where all closed sub-walks are distinct, or perhaps something else. Why is this problem posed in the first place?

Comment: Could someone elaborate on the computational complexity of an algorithm that answers my question? Is it exponential necessarily?

Comment: @n.m.: May I ask you what is the problem with using the term "cycle" in my question? It is because some vertices might be revisited besides the starting and ending nodes?

Comment: @n.m.: Based on the link you provided me, I am looking for the circuits (closed trials).

Comment: So no repeated edges?

Comment: @n.m.: First of all, thank you for helping me with definitions. Yes. No repeated edges.

Comment: @n.m: The close trail also is called "tour"; am I right?

Comment: I think the terminology varies a bit depending on whom you ask, but yes, at least some people call it "tour" (others may call it "circuit" but don't quote me on that).

Answer (score 2):

As @user3386109 pointed out the multigraph stuff is just a red herring.  Solve the problem while ignoring the redundant edges.  If you wish to count taking one of the redundant edges as somehow different, then do so once you have the tour - it's a trivial calculation.

Finding a tour ( not the cycle! ) is the crux.  Here is how I do it:

1. Construct a spanning tree starting at any vertex.  If a spanning tree cannot be found ( several reasons - a multiple component graph, leaf vertices of degree one )  then a tour that visits every vertex at least once does not exist.
2. Do a depth first search through the spanning tree, starting at the root.  If you get stuck on a leaf vertex of the spanning tree "jump" to another unvisited leaf vertex ( use Dijsktra to find the shortest "jump" ) and continue the DFS from there.
3. The DFS will end on a leaf vertex, with no more unvisited leaf vertices. Use the Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path back to the root, or climb down back to the root vertex to complete the tour back at the starting node.

For myself, I am very happy to have found a tour.  However you want to find all the tours, so you have to repeat the above algorithm, iterating over all the vertices as the spanning tree root node and keeping any tours that you find which are novel.

You can find more details about this, with documentation of how run it at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Tour.  That repo also has the C++ code to implement the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is the computational complexity of the proposed algorithm polynomial? If so, then it seems a bit strange to me, as I think the complexity should be at least exponential!

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?  My code runs in a few seconds on graphs of a few hundred vertices, which is fine by me since the practical applications I am concerned with (  to do with route planning for autonomous vehicles ) need no more.  If you have a larger problem to tackle, let me know and I can look into it.

Comment: ravenspoint: By tour, do you mean the closed trail? Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of enumerating all tours is just... enumerating them. Use a DFS but mark visited *edges* (as opposed to visited vertices in the "usual" DFS). Once you return to your starting vertex, check if all vertices are visited, and if so, add the tour to the list of answers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Out of curiosity, if the Hamiltonian cycles are also enumerated, as I think they are the subset of all found tours? Am I right?

Comment: Could you please help me how to compute the number of tours in a directed graph with V vertices and E edges? Is there any formula that at least gives an upper bound for this number?

Comment: I am wondering how your solution is way simpler than user3386109! I am suspicious that something is not in its correct place concerning one of the answers!

Comment: The edges are marked, so that the "next time" the search will use a different redundant edge?  But what about the nodes that have an in-degree of 1 ( e.g. node 2 in example 1 )?  If the in edge is marked than the node will not be visited.  If the edges are unmarked the same tour will be found repeatedly.  Perhaps you intend to mark only edges that are redundant?

Comment: If the link below answers my comment concerning the number of tours in a directed graph, in your opinion?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49764067/how-many-tours-exist-in-a-connected-graph-with-v-vertices

Comment: It can be V! (a complete graph) or E! (a two-vertex multigraph). Not sure what you mean "If the in edge is marked than the node will not be visited", the edge is marked *if an only if* the node at its end is visited. Of course when you backtrack you unmark what you have visited, just like in any DFS.

Comment: No DFS implementation I have seen involves unmarking what has been visited.

Comment: @ravenspoint "No DFS implementation I have seen involves unmarking what has been visited" so you haven't seen many. Any implementation that wants to find *all* objects (as opposed to just the first one) needs to do that.

Comment: Since you are unwilling to provide the details of your algorithm, please provide a link to a DFS implementation, or psuedo code, that behaves in the way say.

Comment: @ravenspoint google "DFS find all paths", there is plenty.

Comment: You are so frugal with your assistance.

Comment: @ravenspoint Please ask a separate question about DFS implementations that unset the visited bit, and I'll do my best to answer it.

Comment: [Example of a graph where an edge (x->y) must be used twice to complete the tour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr6LJ.png).

Comment: @user3386109: Thank you very much for your subtle point. So, you mean that my question should ask for finding the closed walks, not the closed tails(circuits). Am I right?

Comment: @AlexanderJafari Yes, it is a closed walk but it has the additional requirement that all nodes are visited at least once, so "closed walk" is an incomplete description. It's not a trail or circuit (according to the wikipedia definitions) since those require distinct edges. The thing you're looking for can have repeated edges, and repeated nodes. None of the standard terms fully describe what you're looking for, so you need to make up your own word for it. I suggested "tour" in one of my comments, but if you stick with the wikipedia definition, then "tour" isn't correct either.

Comment: If repeated edges are allowed, then there is either zero or an infinite number of these objects (whatever you call them), unless you place some additional restrictions which may or may not be difficult to implement in the code. If repeated edges are not allowed, then some graphs have no such objects and other have a positive finite number, and you can find them with a simple DFS (find all trails/circuits and then filter out those that do not visit all the nodes). I don't know if it's possible to have a more efficient algorithm than that.

Comment: @user3386109: Thank you for your helpful points. So, If I consider closed walks where all nodes are visited at least once (with repeated edges), then there will be infinite closed walks. How should I define my closed walks, then? I think all the closed walks with distinct sub-closed walks. Am I right?

Comment: Closed walks with distinct sub-closed walks is a possible definition but it will be tough to implement efficiently.

Comment: @AlexanderJafari I think the comment by n.m. about repeated edges is important. You need to decide whether the graph in my comment has a solution or not. If it does, then I agree that distinct sub-closed walks is a possible definition. On the other hand, if that graph does not have a solution, then the question is, "what is the minimum modification that allows the graph to be solved?" For example, if adding a second edge from `x` to `y` allows the graph to be solved, then (perhaps) a closed trail *is* what you're looking for.

Comment: @user3386109: Thank you for your help. Please let me think about it.